# Trigger SQL Prestashop

Tags: mysql, sql, prestashop

I'm using Prestashop and I would like to disable an article when a specific price is outdated. 
I have a table `ps_specific_price` with (id_product, from, to (date)). And I can change the active statut in the `ps_product_shop` (id_product, active).
I tried to make a trigger in phpMyadmin :

```
BEGIN
UPDATE ps_product_shop SET active=0 WHERE id_product IN (SELECT id_product FROM ps_specific_price WHERE ps_specific_price.to <= NOW());
UPDATE ps_product_shop SET active=1 WHERE id_product IN (SELECT id_product FROM ps_specific_price WHERE ps_specific_price.to > NOW());
END
```

In the Time field, it's AFTER and in the Event field it's UPDATE.

It doesn't work. When a specific price is finished, the product isn't desactivated.
Here is how I defined the trigger :
[image: Trigger]
Is there an error?
Thanks!

Comment: Where exactly have you defined this 'trigger'? Is it a real SQL [trigger](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html), [event](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-event.html), cron task or something else?

Comment: Can you post the whole trigger?Was it successfully compiled?

Comment: I defined the trigger with phpMyAdmin, in the Trigger field. And yes, it was successfully compiled :)

Comment: If you run the query separately,using SELECT instead of UPDATE do you get any rows?

Comment: I get the expected results. But I don't know if only the time can execute the trigger

Comment: AFTER UPDATE trigger has some restrictions:you cant UPDATE new or old values.Maybe create an event which runs every minute or so with the same queries

Comment: Thanks it works with an event!

Answer (score 0):

you dont need BEGUIN and END
phpmyadmin will add them for you